# Is any Mersenne number $M_p$ divisible by $p+2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

More precisely, does there exist a natural number $p$ such that $(2^p-1)/(p+2)$ is also a natural number? It seems to me that this is a really simple problem (with the answer "no"), but I couldn't find anything on the web. There are some facts known about division by $p+1$, but nothing useful for $p+2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone should double-check this, but my computer seems to be telling me that $${2^{20735}-1\over20737}{\rm\ and\ }{2^{93525}-1\over93527}$$ are natural numbers. No other examples up to 100001.

It appears that these numbers have been [tabulated](http://oeis.org/A173572).

Comment: I think you forgot the $-1$ in the numerator.

Comment: @EuYu, thanks - fixed now.

Comment: I can confirm the computations. Also in case nobody noticed $\frac{2^0-1}{0+2}=0$ is a natural number (to me).

Comment: Is anything known about the asymptotic distribution of these numbers?

Comment: @Sacha, I don't know, but maybe there's some information to be had by following the links at the OEIS reference in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If $p$ is even, $p+2$ cannot divide $2^p-1$

Else p is odd.

If $(p+2)\mid(2^p-1),$ $2^p≡1\pmod{p+2}$ but $2^{\phi(p+2)}≡1\pmod{p+2}$

So, $\operatorname{ord}_{p+2}2$ must divide  $(\phi(p+2),p)$.

If p+2 is prime, $(\phi(p+2),p)=(p+1,p)=1$.

Else $\phi(p+2)<p$ as in that case $\phi(p+2)<p+1$ and  $\phi(p+2)≠p$, if $p$ is odd prime $\implies(\phi(p+2),p)=1$

So if  at least one of $p$ and $p+2$ is odd prime,  $\operatorname{ord}_{p+2}2\mid1$ which is impossible.

When both of them are  composite,

If $p+2=\prod Q_i^{r_i}$ where $r_i$s are positive integers and  $Q_i$ are distinct odd primes,

As $(p,p+2)=(p,2)=1$ as $p$ is odd,

so, $(p,Q_i)=1 \implies  (p, \phi(p+2))= (p, \prod Q_i^{r_i-1}(Q_i-1))=(p, \prod(Q_i-1))$

If $Q_i-1=2^{s_i}q_i$ where $q_i$ is odd number,   $(p, \phi(p+2))=(p, \prod(Q_i-1))$
$=(p, \prod q_i)$ as $p$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

Another proof is as follows. First for $p=2$, it follows because $2^p-1=3<4=p+2$.
For odd primes $p$, there is a theorem (see [Mersenne Prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Prime_Numbers) for proof) that states that every factor of $2^p-1$ is of the form $2kp+1$ for some integer $k\geq0$. Thus we want a $p$ for which $p+2=2kp+1$. There is no such prime because for $p>2$, we have $1<p+2<2p+1$ thus requiring $0<k<1$, a contradiction to the theorem.

Comment: But OP didn't say $p$ was prime.

Comment: In fact $p+2=2kp+1 \implies (2k-1)p=1$